# NSTableView cells ontop of header

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

When I apply a layer to my table cells (or text fields in the cells), they suddenly scroll over my table header. How can I fix this? I've tried applying a layer to the header, but no luck.

```
cell.textField?.wantsLayer = true
cell.textField?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try unchecking 'Floats Group Rows' in the Attributes Inspector on the NSTableView?